# Exact determinant of a Cauchy-like matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, cv.complex-variables, determinants, matrix-theory

> **Question.** Is there a closed-form expression for the determinant of a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with entries 
>   $$
> A_{i,j} = \frac{1 - \delta_{i, j}}{z_i - z_j}, \qquad 1\leq i, j\leq n,
> $$
>   where $z_i$ is a sequence of pairwise distinct complex numbers. The values on the diagonal are $0$.

It looks like a limit of a Cauchy matrix, but with $0$ on the diagonal, I'm particularly interested in the case where the $z_i$ have unit norm.

I welcome any reference, suggestion or special case,

Thanks,

Comment: Nice problem, but no closed formula. :-(

Comment: Note that it is anti symmetric. In particular, for odd n the determinant will be 0 and for even n it will be the square of some rational function.

Comment: I assume $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta, and that the $0/0$ indeterminate form that appears on the diagonal is intended to be $0$?

Comment: Yes, the values along the diagonal are all 0, sorry. It's anti symmetric and I'm in fact interested in the Pfaffian of the matrix.

Comment: In Krattenthaler, Advanced Determinant Calculus https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9902004.pdf you can find a lot of techniques. Perhaps one will do the job or you get inspiration for different directions to follow.

Comment: The denominators factor nicely: $\prod_{i<j}(z_i-z_j)^2$.

Comment: Looking at the Pfaffian as a symmetric function doesn't look completely hopeless.  I get $6m_{1 1 1 1} - m_{2 1 1} + m_{2 2}$ and
$90m_{2 2 2 2 2 2} - 12m_{3 2 2 2 2 1} + 4m_{3 3 2 2 1 1} + 3m_{3 3 2 2 2} - 3m_{3 3 3 2 1} + 6m_{3 3 3 3} + 3m_{4 2 2 2 1 1} - 6m_{4 2 2 2 2} - 3m_{4 3 2 1 1 1} + m_{4 3 2 2 1} + m_{4 3 3 1 1} - m_{4 3 3 2} + 6m_{4 4 1 1 1 1} - m_{4 4 2 1 1} + m_{4 4 2 2}$ where m are the monomial symmetric functions

Comment: This matrix is sometimes known as Trummer's matrix -- this might be a useful search term to you, but my Google-fu returned nothing.